# Insert and get max from structure in constant time

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I need a data structure to store positive (not necessarily integer) values. It must support the following two operations in sublinear time:

1. Add an element.
2. Remove the largest element.

Also, the largest key may scale as N^2, N being the number of elements. In principle, having O(N^2) space requirement wouldn't be a big problem, but if a more efficient option exists in terms of store, it would work better.

I am working in Python, so if such a data structure exists, it would be of help to have an implementation in this language.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such data structure. For example, if there were, sorting would be worst-case linear time:  add all `N` elements in `O(N)` time, then remove the largest element remaining `N` times, again in total `O(N)` time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have modified the original question, allowing any sublinear time for the operations.

Answer (score 1):

the best data structure you can choose for this operations is the heap: [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_data_structure/python_heaps.htm#:~:text=Heap%20is%20a%20special%20tree,is%20called%20a%20max%20heap](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_data_structure/python_heaps.htm#:%7E:text=Heap%20is%20a%20special%20tree,is%20called%20a%20max%20heap).

with this data structure both adding an element and removing the max are O(log(n)).

this is the most used data structure when you need a lot of operations on the max element, for example is commonly used to implement priority queues

Comment: I have implemented a heap in Python using the heapq library. The algorithm now performs better, but is still somehow slow. Do you know if implementing it in C++ would be significantly faster?

Comment: I don't think so. If you share your problem we may find a different approach which performs better.

Comment: one more thing: are you sure you used the MAX Heap implementation? Because the default is the MIN heap and doesn't do the remove max operation in O(log(n)) while it does the remove min operation in O(log(n))

Answer (score 0):

Although constant time may be impossible, depending on your input constraints, you might consider a [y-fast-trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-fast_trie), which has `O(log log m)` time operations and `O(n)` space, where `m` is the range, although they work with integers, taking advantage of the bit structure. One of the supported operations is next higher or lower element, which could let you keep track of the highest when the latter is removed.

Comment: The OP didn't say much, but did say these aren't necessarily ints. y-fast tries (and x-fast tries, and van Emde Boas trees) rely on that their possible keys are constrained to ints no larger than a pre-determined maximum int `M`. That allows them to do part of the work with `O(1)` int arithmetic and/or bit-fiddling. Note too that the `M` in their `O(log log M)` is that maximum possible key, _not_ the distribution - or even number - of keys currently in use.

Comment: @TimPeters without more details from the OP, it seems hard to rule this option out. Thanks for reminding me to add a note about the range.

Comment: They did say "(not necessarily integer)" - which rules it out for me ;-)

Comment: @גלעדברקן Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I don´t think this structure will work, as my data may include non-integer values. Also, the largest key can scale as n^2 (I have added this information to my question)

Comment: @NahuelAlmeira if O(n^2) space is not a problem and the largest  key scales as n^2, that makes me very curious. Could you please specify the exact range of values you expect and how many additional decimal digits (the digits after the point) each element in this range can have?

Comment: @NahuelAlmeira and equally important, please share the maximum value N can have.